# Bash error echo a command

Tags: bash, scripting, echo

I have a problem. I need to show a echo from a while, I use two echo the first one work but the second it give a error.

```
#!/bin/bash
conexiuni="/tmp/conexiuni"
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
netstat -tuan | grep $1 | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n > $conexiuni
else
netstat -tuan  | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n > $conexiuni
fi

cat $conexiuni | while read line
do
  con=`echo ''$line'' | awk '{print $1}'`
  ip=`echo ''$line'' | awk '{print $2}'`
  if [ "$con" -gt "4" ]; then
       `echo -e "$ip" >> /var/log/drop_sc_ip`
       `echo -e "$ip"`
  fi
done
if [  -f "$conexiuni" ];
then
    `rm -rf $conexiuni`
fi
```

The error is :

```
./show_conn: line 15: 8.97.80.2: command not found
./show_conn: line 15: 8.76.109.13: command not found
./show_conn: line 15: 8.33.15.2: command not found
./show_conn: line 15: 9.118.226.3: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this part without the backticks:

```
if [ "$con" -gt "4" ]; then
       echo -e "$ip" >> /var/log/drop_sc_ip
       echo -e "$ip"
fi
```

also same in this part:

```
rm -rf $conexiuni
```

with the backticks, it first executes what is inside the backticks and then tries to execute the output of the backticks.

and change the loop:

```
while read con ip
do
    if [ "$con" -gt "4" ]; then
       echo -e "$ip" >> /var/log/drop_sc_ip
       echo -e "$ip"
    fi
done < $conexiuni
```